# Read SEI data from a HEVC video with FFmpeg

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, libavcodec, hevc

I’ve been trying to create some HEVC videos programmatically using FFmpeg C++ libraries and x265 encoder, using  [`--master-display`](http://x265.readthedocs.org/en/default/cli.html#cmdoption--master-display), [`--max-cll`](http://x265.readthedocs.org/en/default/cli.html#cmdoption--max-cll) and other SEI data options from x265.  Now, to make sure this information is being written correctly I’ll like to know how I can read back this SEI data from the generated video file, preferably using the FFmpeg C++ library and functions.

I have implemented a video decoder which works using `av_read_frame()` and decoding frames from each `AVPacket` obtained. I’m not sure if somehow I can get SEI information before this process, from these packets or with a similar approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SEI reading code lives [here](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavcodec/hevc_sei.c;h=8ae680e5ebbc628513592112c977561e615b36d1;hb=HEAD#l200), you can add debug messages to see if individual values are being read as expected. The consumer code for the sei bits is [here](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavcodec/hevc.c;h=157cdaeb3d9380d313363f2612336d25334945aa;hb=HEAD#l2548), and it calculates the angle at which the video should be presented to the user. This is exported in AVFrame as [display matrix side-data](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#ggae01fa7e427274293aacdf2adc17076bca3e01b882b6fa04724076067d6d9f8b69), which you can read using the API in display.h ([source](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavutil/display.h;h=c0cfee326d193eede89d975fce636638e74e9c3d;hb=HEAD), [doxy](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/display_8h.html), [annotated source](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/display_8h_source.html)).

The application can then use this angle to rotate the image accordingly, e.g. using the [rotate avfilter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate).

Comment: @ronald-s-bultje Yes, _set_side_data_ was the correct place to obtain the bits. I'm sending them as side data and I'm able to read them back. Thanks a lot for your help! (Sorry for the super late reply)